# How can I update and get values in Windows Forms while moving one form to other form (like cookies)?

Tags: c#, windows, vb.net, winforms, windows-ce

How can I update and get values in a Windows Forms application while moving one form to other form (like cookies)?

I need to update the values to some variable and again I am going to refer stored values and need to do some calculations.

I have used cookies in ASP.NET but I am not able to find out the same concept in .NET Windows Forms (C#).

How can these issues be resolves?

Comment: what are you trying to do? move data between forms?  Your question is not very clear, please clarify

Answer (score 1):

You can use object references.

Answer (score 1):

You can decalre a read/write Property for each variable you want to be available in another form and the use them for sharing your data.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to declare variables to be public, either in a global module or in any form.

```
public x as double
```

If it is declared in a module, you can access it with the variable name only. To access data declared in another form, use that form name with the variable: `form1.x = 7`

Another way is to declare a property in a form or other class.

Answer (score 0):

A really simple way of getting cookie-like functionality would be to declare a static string dictionary in Program (Program.cs)
`public static System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary SortOfLikeCookies = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringDictionary();` and read/write string values using `Program.SortOfLikeCookies["Name"] = "Value";`